# Testing the namespace

Tags: google-app-engine, testing, junit, namespaces, multi-tenant

In my app I have a method that uses one of its parameters to set the namespace. The code works but when I try to run tests on it I get a `NullPointerException` at `NamespaceManager.set()`.

```
    public String create(Bar bar) {
        NamespaceManager.set(bar.getFoo.toString());
        // more code
        return NamespaceManager.get();
}
```

I have also tried using void as return type, but the error was the same.

I now wonder if this error comes from an error in my code or is it impossible to access the `NamespaceManager` in a unit test.

**Edit**
The test code:

```
 @Before
    public void before() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setFoo(1L);

        CSDatastoreService csDatastore = Mockito.mock(CSDatastoreServiceImpl.class);

        SController ctrl = new SController(csDatastore);
   } 



@Test
public void createSetsNamaspaceToFooOfBar() {
    Assert.assertSame(ctrl.create(bar), bar.getFoo().toString());
}
```

Comment: Is the exception really from `NamespaceManager.set()`, or from your `bar.getFoo().toString()`?  If you split it into two lines the stack trace will give you a clue.

Comment: It works when I use the code outside of a test. Also, if I do System.out.println(NamespaceManager.get()) and System.out.println(bar.getFoo.toString()) I get the same (expected) results. It's only when it runs in a test that I get errors.

Comment: When you saw "run test" mean junit test?

Comment: Yes, in Eclipse: Run as: Junit test

Comment: @LisaMM did you fix this, running into the same !?

Comment: @koma no, sorry. If I ever find it I will post the answer here.

Comment: @LisaMM figured it out, LocalServiceTestHelper not setup, order of execution in my tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance of `com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper` and call `setup()` before making any calls to the NamespaceManager in your unit tests.

example

```
public final static LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(
            new LocalUserServiceTestConfig(),
            new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig()
                    .setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100.0f)
                    .setNoIndexAutoGen(true));
```

And further down :

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    helper.setUp();
}
```